# Python: Is there a way I can add a footnote to word document?

Tags: python-2.7, docx, python-docx

I have tried the following with python-docx:

```
section = self.document.sections[0]
footer = section._sectPr.footer
footer.text = "I am here"
```

I couldn't find a clear footer/header directions in docx documentations. Is there a work around to cover this gap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The work around is:

- Create a document with python-docx.
- Change the name to 'init.docx'
- Comment any adding-new-style code
- Open 'init.docx'
- Delete everything
- Save it.
- Add footnote/Headers to 'init.docx'
- Change `self.document = Document('')` to `self.document = Document('init.docx')`.

Comment: Here is progress on the issue in github for anyone interested: https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/1