# Is there a workaround for adding Microsoft Word footnotes dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, doc, python-docx

Currently I'm using Python Flask to build an application to generate a formatted document from data stored in sql database. My idea was to detect the footnotes marks in the text and render footnotes on the run:

```
text = ''' This is a sample text {{footnotes:Yes it is!}} It's just that. '''
footnote = text[text.find("{{footnotes:")+12:text.find("}}")]
```

However, it seems that python-docx does not offer footnotes manipulation at this very moment.Are there any other packages in Python (or node.js, preferably not for the application would be made from scratch all over again) to add footnotes to .doc file?

Is it a viable route to first make the document Markdown and then somehow convert it into .docx with footnotes properties?

Comment: If you are crafty enough you could read the .xml that created the .docx and use that. That's all the creators or `python-docx` did after all...

Comment: @Reedinationer That's a really road... But thanks for the advice, I'll try if It turns out necessary.

Comment: Just to clarify though, you are interested in footnotes, and not footers right?

Comment: Maybe you could use the `FOOTNOTE_TEXT` like on https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/enum/WdBuiltinStyle.html?highlight=footnote?

Comment: @Reedinationer Yes I want the footnotes not the footer. it seems to me that what FOOTNOTE_TEXT do is changing the style of the footnotes instead of manipulating the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `python-docx` documentation (https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html):

> The feature set is still being built out, so you can’t add or change things like headers or footnotes yet

However you can locate them with the xml structure as discussed at https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/1

Or perhaps a better solution is shown at [Python: Is there a way I can add a footnote to word document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38795791/python-is-there-a-way-i-can-add-a-footnote-to-word-document/38923927#38923927)

If I understand this solution he is suggesting to essentially create a template with your desired footnote on it, and then load that into python. This wouldn't be "dynamic" though so is likely not what you're looking for either.

It looks like in 2014 one of the developers of `python-docx` had a conversation at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-docx/4iQoFG2X03I where he says he wouldn't work on the project for a few months. Maybe you could try to contact him there or through the main `docx` site and help him build out the module (so you don't have to tackle all the xml handling on your own). Otherwise you will have to find another solution (you mentioned Node.js, but I have no knowledge of it so I cannot help there). Best of luck!

Comment: Note that support for headers and footers was recently added. Not footnotes yet though.

Comment: @scanny yes headers and footers have been added (I’m not sure if they are finished yet though). Footnotes are still backlogged though. The developer said in the google conversation I linked that he had them all at the same priority though, so they may come out soon (sooner still if OP helps out!).

Comment: A rare gem of an answer to an obscure question.  Well-researched and with links.